# Landscape with OIDC how to assign permissions to users?

Tags: permissions, landscape

I installed the landscape quickstart. Logged in as initial admin user. All fine.

Then enabled OIDC following the (brief) instructions (link below).
Logged in with my OIDC account. All fine.

Except, the user I logged in as has no permissions and an empty dashboard. "Accounts and Roles" says "You are not a member of any account."

So, what scopes does the OIDC provider need to send to Landscape for it to recognise who is an admin/member of the account??

And/Or, how do I login with the original admin user created after the installation? (Usually apps have a backdoor login URL somewhere so you can still login if your provider fails.)

(NB a link to the document where all this is explained properly would be handy, I'm sure I'll have other questions soon enough. I did search and failed to find. Other than : https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem-auth which explains virtually nothing.)

Comment: https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/landscape-administrators

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the bit where I said "empty dashboard"?
eg no Administrators tab. Nowhere to type an email address to invite someone.
If I disable OIDC and invite my own email address, then it says "max is already a member" (or whatever I call myself with my email address)

Comment: I did, yet after a short look at the docs I came to the believe you had not tried what you posted as answer - and thought this hint might be enough. Knowing that documentations of open source services that are also used for generating income are mostly insufficient. Happy to see you figured it out. Peace

Answer (score 0):

Urgh, had to invite an email address that exists in OIDC. They have to ignore the invite. Change the config, restart the server. Then they can accept the invite.

Comment: Still doesn't answer how to manage authorisation from the OIDC provider. May not be possible (_weak_).

Comment: Canonical has admitted to me in several cases their documentation is sparse.  NORMALLY you would have access to Canonical paid support if you have a full Landscape license, if you are working off the free version then you're on your own to figure this stuff out :P